# mesh not moving in pose mode

Tags: rigging, rigify, pose-mode

I am trying to animate a dog. I used the rigify wolf skeleton and succeded in creating the rig
[image: dog in pose mode]
But the mesh isnt moving with the rig when I grab it.
What am I missing ?
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: hello, please share your file (upload and copy paste the URL it will generate): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I would love to - however the file is to big. I tryed it with a different model and a huma linke mesh - same thing so I think I am missing something fundamental.

Comment: Hard to tell without the file, you can use another platform and share the link here, for example send the file to yourself with wetransfer dans copy paste the link

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuwYMqBOop2HjKcbolQDl2wieVzLtg?e=uVvGgE

Here you go, Really apprechiating you taking the time to look at it. I definetly want to learn what I do wrong

Comment: I'm not sure why you have 2 armatures (rig and metarig), also you must deparent rig from Object_2, it's Object_2 that is supposed to be parented to a rig

Comment: metarig is created by rigify I guess and then the rig is created. I have the rig being parent to the mesh here

Comment: I just retoped the mesh with instantMeshes to around 100k to make sure the messy topology wasnt an issue. What makes me wonder: ctrl-P doesnt bring up "Automatic weight" option. I used the object meue ->parenting for that

Comment: I don't know metarig enough but shouldn't the armature be one piece? For the parentage, it's the mesh that needs to be parented to the armature, not the other way around

Comment: I believe I followed the tutorials for rigify step by step.... And yes - the amature is the parent of the mesh. if its wrong in the file i alreadyfixed it

Comment: OK I hope someone that knows rigify better than me will be able to answer

Comment: dude - you where right. In the tutorial they did the parenting the wrong way. since you pointed it out I double checked it - seems to work now. thanks a bunch

Comment: what about the double armature?

Comment: I didn't notice. Cleaned everything up now. Thanks